# Combine *ngFor interpolations to access global variable

Tags: angular

Using Angular I have created the following HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions.questions; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i == counter">
    <button *ngFor="let item of question | keyvalue; let buttonIndex = index" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary surveyButton" type="button" value={{item.value}} (tap)="makeSelection(item.value)">
    {{item.value}}

      <span>
        {{prevSelection + buttonIndex}}
      </span>

    </button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

I have global variables `prevSelection1`, `prevSelection2`, `prevSelection3`, and `prevSelection4`.

Using `{{prevSelection + buttonIndex}}`, I was hoping to display all four of these variables, however the concatenation within the interpolation is not working.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you create a demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: your question is not clear explain more clearly

Comment: do you mean whats there in `prevSelection1`  to be displayed after concatenation {{'prevSelection' + 1}} ?

Comment: did you give this a try `{{ this[prevSelection + buttonIndex]}}` .

Comment: please mention the type of prevSelection + buttonIndex in the question...

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can create object and the try to use it.
    selection = {
       prevSelection1 :'abc',
       prevSelection2 :'def',
       prevSelection3 :'pqr',
       prevSelection4 :'xyz',
    }
<ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions.questions; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i == counter">
    <button *ngFor="let item of question | keyvalue; let buttonIndex = index" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary surveyButton" type="button" value={{item.value}} (tap)="makeSelection(item.value)">
    {{item.value}}

      <span>
        {{selection['prevSelection' + buttonIndex]}}
      </span>

    </button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Hope this works for you